# How to turn a 3d model made in Qgis2threejs into a shareable file

Tags: qgis, 3d, html, qgis2threejs

I have made a 3d model using Qgis2threejs, I can open the viewer in my browser and it works fine. I want to be able to provide someone with a link to the viewer, rather than have to send them an html file, how do I do this?

Basically, what is the easiest way to make an exported 3d model made in Qgis2threejs into something that is easily shareable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can upload the export folder to your website. Creating a directory protection would be good to ensure that only certain people have access.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way I can do this without having a website? Ideally I'd like for anyone to be able to click on a link to access a viewer. It's for an academic publication so I don't have the funds to have a whole website!

Sorry I am sure this is probably not the most appropriate place to be asking this question, I am not SUPER techincally minded so I'm struggling to figure out how to do it/if it can be done!

Comment: OK. There are cost free file sharing provider. I have no account. Please look out: I think the most provider have no directory protection for free. When your project is seen by everyone, you must sure, that you have a correct copyright 3D interactive map. For example you can not use layers with images from google map / satellite.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look out!